# Unittests. cross_15_percent_threshold() failure;

Tags: unit-tests

I execute unit tests. For example, that one:

```
./build/unittests/unit_test -t eosio_system_tests/fail_without_auth
```

And receive failure:

> assertion failure with message: cannot undelegate bandwidth until the
>   chain is activated (at least 15% of all tokens participate in voting)
>       thread-0  wasm_interface.cpp:930 eosio_assert

I would be grateful if someone would tell me what the problem is and what should I check first?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer:

The `eosiosystem::min_activated_stake` (contracts/eosio.system/producer_pay.cpp) value was bigger than 150 billion.